# Loops in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, loops

I want to run a block of code in SQLite Studio for multiple tables (years):

```
select * from table_1;
select * from table_2;
...
select * from table_20;
```

Is there a way I can iterate with a single line of code without needing to write it for each of them? Something equivalent to 'for loops' in Python or Macros in SAS.

Comment: Why is your database design _so broken_ like that? You _should not_ be splitting tables up by year...

Comment: The only way to dynamically specify a table name is to generate an SQL query with the table name in it. If you can, the best way would probably be to use something like a Python script to generate and execute the queries. If not, the only real way is to generate the query as a string and tell the engine to execute it.

Comment: There are no stored procedures in sqlite. However, you may encounter sqlite as part of another programming environment like Python, Java (e.g. Android), and so forth which could support looping. Alternatively, if you are looking for a complete Sqlite solution and want to repeat something, I'd recommend you (1) review your database design to see if it is fit for purpose, (2) consider using Views / Indexes.